# Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure

Tags: appium, robotframework

I am running automating android apps using robot framework:
i have imported libraries those are selenium2library and android library.
      Initially i launched apps using goto url keyword:
 where i  gave argument as url of my apps.
 after running  test script i got ::

```
Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: 
Multiple keywords with name 'Capture Page Screenshot' found. Give 
the full name of the keyword you want to use:     
AppiumLibrary.Capture Page Screenshot     
Selenium2Library.Capture Page Screenshot.
```

How to resolve it. Could anybody tell me some solutions.

Comment: Could You please be more clear about the problem?
I am sorry if I am the only one but I do not understand the issue here. Could You please provide step-by-step instruction of your problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Robot is telling you that there are two keywords named `Capture Page Screenshot`. One is defined by `Selenium2Library`, and one is defined by `AppiumLibrary`. One or both of those also have instructed robot to run `Capture Page Screenshot` when there is an error. However, because there are two, robot doesn't know which one it is supposed to call.

There are at least a couple of solutions. The first is to use the built-in keyword [Set library search order](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Library%20Search%20Order), to instruct robot on the order in which to search for the keywords. The second is to tell robot specifically which version to run. The solution might also be as simple as *not* importing both libraries into a single suite.

### Setting the search order

To set the search order, add something like this to the start of your test -- perhaps in the suite setup:

```
*** Settings ***
| Suite Setup | Set Library Search Order | AppiumLibrary | Selenium2Library
```

That instructs robot to first examine `AppiumLibrary` and then `Selenium2Library` to resolve conflicts.

From the keyword documentation:

> The library search order is used to resolve conflicts when a keyword
>   name in the test data matches multiple keywords. The first library (or
>   resource, see below) containing the keyword is selected and that
>   keyword implementation used. If the keyword is not found from any
>   library (or resource), test executing fails the same way as when the
>   search order is not set.

### Set explicit keyword name

When importing `Selenium2Library` and `AppiumLibrary` you can specify which command to run on failure. The default is `Capture page screenshot`, which is the root of the problem since there are two keywords with that name. You can tell robot explicitly which one to use.

For example:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Selenium2Library | run_on_failure=AppiumLibrary.CapturePageScreenshot
| Library | AppiumLibrary | run_on_failure=AppiumLibrary.CapturePageScreenshot
```

If you do not wish to change how you import the library, each also provides a keyword named [Register keyword to run on failure](http://jollychang.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/doc/AppiumLibrary.html#Register%20Keyword%20To%20Run%20On%20Failure) which you can use in a setup step to register the fully qualified keyword name.

Comment: How about if I have 3 test cases and I want X,Y  to run with Library A and Z with Library B?  Is there anyway to indicate that at Settings? Thank you.