# Robot Framework auto log generation issue with method 'Capture Page Screenshot' in case of both Appium and Selenium libraries

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, robotframework

For my application, I have to create data on the web application and validate that in the mobile application, so my code supports both Appium and Selenium methods. In a single test-suite file I am calling both the selenium and Appium methods and everything is running successfully.

But whenever any test-case fails for any reason, the robot framework auto-log file fails to understand which method should be used to capture page screenshot [Selenium OR Appium]? It throws the following warning and doesn't capture any screenshot.

```
Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: Multiple keywords with name 'Capture Page Screenshot' found. Give the full name of the keyword you want to use:
    AppiumLibrary.Capture Page Screenshot
    SeleniumLibrary.Capture Page Screenshot
```

In the test-suite file, we can define **Appium.Capture Page Screenshot** or **Selenium.Capture Page Screenshot** but for automatic log creation how we can resolve this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32755781/keyword-capture-page-screenshot-could-not-be-run-on-failure)

Answer (score 2):

#### SeleniumLibrary can be imported with several optional arguments

```
timeout=5.0,
implicit_wait=0.0,
run_on_failure=Capture Page Screenshot,
screenshot_root_directory=None,
plugins=None,
event_firing_webdriver=None
```

```
timeout: Default value for timeouts used with Wait ... keywords.

implicit_wait: Default value for implicit wait used when locating elements.

run_on_failure: Default action for the run-on-failure functionality.

screenshot_root_directory: Path to folder where possible screenshots are created or 
EMBED. See Set Screenshot Directory keyword for further details about EMBED. If not 
given, the directory where the log file is written is used.

plugins: Allows extending the SeleniumLibrary with external Python classes.

event_firing_webdriver: Class for wrapping Selenium with EventFiringWebDriver
```

The `run_on_failure` Argument schould solve your problem for the Selenium Screenshots

There is a similare Argument for the Appium Library

Import the Librarys like this:

```
Library SeleniumLibrary  run_on_failure=SeleniumLibrary.Capture Page Screenshot
Library AppiumLibrary  run_on_failure=AppiumLibrary.Capture Page Screenshot
```

If this doesnt fix the Problem try it with specified Test Teardowns

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to call both of them in teatdown:

```
Run Keyword and Ignore Error    AppiumLibrary.Capture Page Screenshot
Run Keyword and Ignore Error    SeleniumLibrary.Capture Page Screenshot
```

Comment: Note that this way screenshots will be taken even if the test case has passed. This potentially could  create large outputs. So I would suggest using the  `Run Keyword If Test Failed` as well.